# Azure Search - handling dates of birth in different formats

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have two fields in our SQL database/Azure Search index that contain dates of birth in multiple formats including just numbers in all different sequences, words, and any variation thereof.  To further complicate things, it's possible the fields have other text in it like "DOB" or a person's name.  We unfortunately can't achieve consistency because of the vast sources all over the world from which we're pulling this data.

How would this best be handled in Azure Search? We can require from our clients one consistent mandatory DOB format in their query, but is there any way Azure Search can take that and look for it in many different date formats?  Should we instead be looking for a way to create a new field in our table that attempts to standardize the dates of birth?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your scenario a bit more? Are you looking to be able to perform structured filters on the DOB fields (e.g. -- "get me all documents where DOB is after 1940"), or full-text search on the DOB field (e.g. -- "Enter your DOB:"; user enters "Jan. 1, 1940" or "1/1/1940" or "1940-01-01" and it matches), or some combination of both?

Comment: @BruceJohnston we do not need any type of filter scenario.  Our clients will be querying on a person's name and that person's DOB (think pre-employment check).  So the second scenario you mention is what we would be using.  We can force the user to enter the DOB in only one format to at least take some of the variable out of it.  But the DOB's are stored in our DB in many different formats, as mentioned.

Comment: If you're storing a date, put it in a date data type. In other words, your last sentence is what you should be doing: when you import the data, clean the data at that time and load it into a new column of data type `date`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hey Nick good to hear from you again!  Ok thanks for the suggestion.  I will have to research how exactly how to accomplish this.  Perhaps I'll start a new thread about this subject.

Comment: Oh Hi - you are certainly very busy. Cleaning data is a tricky subject. It's likely you'll be able to clean a lot automatically but there is always that bugbear: does 5/4/2017 mean 4th May or 5th April? There's no answer to that one! If you start a new thread please explain your current upload process and technologies etc. Personally I would probably just run a whole bunch of UPDATE statements that account for various cases.

Comment: @Stpete111 Given that you're wanting to search instead of filter, what matters is what the user *thinks* the date means, not necessarily what it actually means, right? :-)  I talked to one of my colleagues about this scenario and he should follow up with an answer hopefully some time today. Some of our analyzers are apparently smart enough to understand certain date formats, but I will let him explain the details as I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: @BruceJohnston fantastic, thanks Bruce, I look forward to reading it.

Comment: @BruceJohnston we're still highly interested in this, so please let me know if your colleague still plans to provide insight.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stpete111 Working on it

Comment: @BruceJohnston checking back in on this.  Any progress?  Thanks.

Comment: @Stpete111 Janusz answered on 4/28.

Comment: @BruceJohnston ah ok, this is the answer below from user called Yahnoosh?  I didn't realize he was your colleague.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could help you with this problem is Microsoft language analyzers that try to normalize dates in different formats, where possible. You can use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to see how the Microsoft English analyzer processes text that represents dates. For example, for the following request

```
 {
   "text": "2015/13/04",
   "analyzer": "en.microsoft"
 }
```

the analyzer produces a token that represents the normalized date:

> dd20150413

Notice, the analyzer recognized that the number 13 represents the day and 03 is the month. The same token would be generated for text **April 13th 2015** or **13-04-2015**.

This means, that users searching using any of the supported formats will match documents with dates that were recognized as the same.

If the default behavior of the Microsoft analyzer is not sufficient, you can always create a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search) with Microsoft analyzer at its core. To learn more about the default behavior of the search engine and how to customize it, please read the following article: [How full text search work in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture)

Comment: Great help Yahnoosh, I will look into this and see if it's the answer!